# Remove Section Index In Table view Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I simply want to have a grouped table view without drawing the side section index part that gets drawn automatically.

I could only find

```
tblProducts.SectionIndexMinimumDisplayRowCount = 1000000000;
```

but this only doesn't draw the section index but it still reserves it's space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [UITableViewSource.SectionIndexTitles Method](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/MonoTouch.UIKit.UITableViewSource.SectionIndexTitles/)

The method above returns `an array of titles to be displayed as an index on the table view`, you just need to return `null`, the SectionIndex will never appear.

```
public override String[] SectionIndexTitles (UITableView tableView)
{
    return null;
}
```